# Typescript array without repetition

Tags: arrays, typescript

I want to make a type of array that does not allow repetitions, and it cannot be a tuple, it must have a free order

I have:
`type Options = Array<'opt1' | 'opt2' | 'opt3'>`

With that this is correct:
`const options: Options = ['opt2', 'opt3', 'opt1']`
`const options: Options = ['opt2', 'opt1']`

But this is correct, and I want it not to be correct, that is, not to allow repetitions
`const options: Options = ['opt2', 'opt3', 'opt3']`

Comment: TypeScript doesn’t have a specific type that works that way, especially if you don’t want to use tuples.  You can validate a tuple type with a generic helper function but I don’t know if you’re interested in any sort of refactoring or just “sorry this won’t work”.  How do you want to proceed?

Comment: I wonder if this is an "XY problem".

Comment: If you want to guarantee uniqueness, use a `Set<'opt1' | 'opt2' | 'opt3'>` But your question seems a bit like you want to throw a compile error on such a situation. This is not possible

Comment: @Teneff  you can use `Set<'opt1' | 'opt2' | 'opt3'>` for type safety ..